# Oracle trigger update on two tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

My question is: is it possible to create trigger for update operation which handles update operation on two tables. These tables would be defined after ON statement in TRIGGER definition.

Comment: It's not possible. You need to define two separate triggers.

Comment: What sort of logic do you want to implement?

Comment: Not directly, no. But, if you create a **view** as a join of those two tables, then you'd create the **INSTEAD OF** trigger(s) which would handle that; you'd update a view, and the trigger would perform appropriate updates in both of those tables.

Comment: Not directly.  To implement common code, create the trigger plsql block as a stored procedure, then each of the triggers (one per table) can call that procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to put two tables in the `ON` clause in a trigger. But you can create two triggers, one for each table. You can also create an [updatable view](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm) with an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, as @Littlefoot suggests.